# Remove Default Wordpress Fields From Widget Form in Admin

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a widget for Wordpress but would like to remove some of the default form fields in the widget admin. Fields such as 'Container', 'Hide the widget title' and 'Text Alignment'. I can probably do this with Javascript but would prefer to do it with PHP if that is possible. I did come across an article that suggested this was not possible but it was a couple of years old. Does anyone know if this can be done and if so point me in the right direction? 
Thanks.